# After calling read() my InputStream beacomes empty

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

im making a form to upload several images to a blob field in a mysql databases.

In a servlet i get all the images uploaded by users using a type="file".

Before inserting the images into the database, i have to check if the type="file" is empyt or not. 
For doing this, according to the corrent structure of my code i do this:

```
  if(allegatoInputStream.read()>-1){....  
//allegatoInputStream is my InputStream
```

But, after i call the read() method, my InputStream becomes empty, so i have nothing to insert in my blob field.

i did something like this

```
InputStream InputStream_FOR_THE_CHECK = blablabla.getInputStream();
  if(InputStream_FOR_THE_CHECK.read()>-1){....
```

But i don't think this is the right way to do what i want to do

Comment: You can store it in a temp variable as you do that..`int c;if((c=allegatoInputStream.read())>-1)`, but I don't think that one `read` is making your Stream empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the stream in a [`PushbackInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html), read one byte to see if there is content, then push back the byte if there is. As long as you then use the same instance of `PushbackInputStream` when you process the file content, that byte will then be part of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Your read() call reads a byte from the stream and throws it away. You need to store the result in a variable, test it for -1, and if it isn't, *use it*. It's the value of the next byte in the stream.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `inputStream.available()`. From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()):

> Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream. The next invocation might be the same thread or another thread. A single read or skip of this many bytes will not block, but may read or skip fewer bytes.
>
> Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.
>
> A subclass' implementation of this method may choose to throw an IOException if this input stream has been closed by invoking the close() method.

In your scenario:

```
if(allegatoInputStream.available()>0){....  
//allegatoInputStream is my InputStream
```

Comment: That's useful *if* there is data available to be read without blocking *and if* available() returns a non-zero result under that circumstance, which what you've quoted clearly says it isn't obliged to do. It's not a solution to this problem, or most others either.

Comment: What I have quoted is the JavaDoc from an abstract class. It depends on the type of `InputStream` being used, as different ones implement `available()` differently. If the `InputStream` in question supports this behavior, this can be used.